# Is there a big RSA Data Set

Tags: rsa

Is there a big dataset containing RSA public $(n,e)$ and private keys $d$ and primes $p,q$ where $n = p.q$ ?

Comment: What do you need that set for? Since you want private keys too, the easiest solution is generating such a set yourself.

Comment: If you meant a list of all *possible* keypairs, [this may help put things into perspective](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/is-it-feasible-to-build-an-index-of-prime-factors) (by the way, saving $d$ is unnecessary if you already know $p$ and $q$ as it can be efficiently calculated from $e$).

Answer (score 3):

No.  You can generate such a dataset for yourself by generating lots of RSA keypairs yourself.  Therefore, there's no need for such a dataset (and no reason why anyone would publish one).

Comment: Indeed. There are big datasets containing RSA public $(n,e)$ in actual use, and some of them come with revocation certificates; but that does not give $d$, $p$, $q$. There are a few small datasets of test RSA keys matching the question, except for size of the set. Some sites, including [this one](http://www.hanewin.net/encrypt/rsa/rsa-test.htm), will generate one such key for you (but it should not be trusted for anything other than a test).