# Adi Shamir's secret database of all primes

Tags: rsa, reference-request, factoring, database

I was going through [**these presentation slides**](http://crypto.2013.rump.cr.yp.to/55e2988c4ed3c9f635c9a4c3f52fa0b1.pdf) (PDF) on  Crypto 2013.

It summarizes the paper, Factoring RSA keys from certiﬁed smart cards: Coppersmith in the wild.

In the last slide, it was mentioned that one possible future work to be done is to use the *“Adi Shamir's secret database of all primes”* to attempt breaking RSA-1024. I tried to Google for *“Adi Shamir's secret database of all primes”*, but I can't find anything. Does anyone have any idea about this "database"?

Comment: That database is to cryptography venues what the [Dahu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dahu) is to French summer camps. Also see the answers to [this](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/is-it-feasible-to-build-an-index-of-prime-factors). $\;$ The three other 'future work' items in the presentation are in the same vein.

Comment: @fgrieu I tried to come up with something more…  *“meaty”*, but your comment practically answers the question on-point. So, maybe it would make sense to post it as an answer? I’ld surely upvote it.

Comment: It exists, but you can't select from it because the programmer forgot to put a with(nolock) on the insert sproc.

Comment: Now the record is [340 million](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76757/18298)

Answer (score 8):

*Adi Shamir's secret database of all primes* is to cryptography venues what the [*Dahu*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dahu) is to French summer camps. For why, see the answers to this [related question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/is-it-feasible-to-build-an-index-of-prime-factors).

The three other *future work* items in the quoted presentation are in the same vein (*Breaking RSA-1024 with Fermat factoring*; *Breaking RSA-1024 using* $1024 = 2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2$; *Breaking RSA-1024 using Intel's new RDRAND_NSAKEY instruction*).

Note: serious work and some further progress did occur after Cypto 2013; see these [updated slides](http://hyperelliptic.org/tanja/vortraege/20131205.pdf) of Asiacrypt 2013, also linked from DJB's [smartfacts page](http://smartfacts.cr.yp.to/).

Comment: That is amazing, I can't remember how many [snipe hunts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snipe_hunt) I've done.