# Will a list of all prime numbers upto certain number of bits compromise crytopgraphic algorithms based on prime factorization?

Tags: hash, rsa, diffie-hellman, prime-numbers

I understand that many cryptographic algorithms depend on the difficulty of large prime factorization.

Will a  list of all prime numbers upto certain number of bits make it easy for an attacker to compromise such algorithms?

Comment: Does this [How big an RSA key is considered secure today?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1982/18298) satisfies you? and this [Adi Shamir's secret database of all primes](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18026/18298) and [Is it feasible to build an index of prime factors?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1013/18298) and this is an another attack way [The GCD strikes back to RSA in 2019 - Good randomness is the only solution?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76757/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka Thank you! Very important, useful, and interesting read list.

Comment: The last one ( index of prime factors) is your dupe, AFAIK.